# Carousel/slider select to load main image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

I am working on a website for a friend, and I have come across a strange problem. The template uses an owl carousel, basically your run of the mill slider, however I also wanted to have the it so that when the user clicks on a carousel image it replaces the main image above. I worked out the following code, however it only works in the intended manner after selecting the 2nd image in the carousel, then the first image. Its as though the main image doesn't get the `display:none` property until after doing this sequence.

You can see the example on: http://felixplakolb.com/portfolio-single/138649524

http://codepen.io/afagard/pen/KMpQQN

JQUERY:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function () {
    // gallery setup    
    var Img='.'+$(".gallery_image img#active").attr('class')
    $("#owl-related-works a").click(function(){
        var ImgId = '.'+$(this).attr("href").slice(1);
        if (ImgId!=Img) {
             $(Img).hide();
             $(Img).attr({id:'inactive-gallery'});
             $(ImgId).show();
             $(ImgId).attr({id:'active'})
        }
        Img=ImgId;
      return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Carousel:

```
    <?php } elseif ($type = 'Photography') { ?>
    <section class="related-projects pb-90">
        <div class="container">
            <h4 class="heading-inline"><?php echo $name . ' Gallery'; ?></h4>
            <div class="customNavigation right">
                <a class="btn prev"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a>
                <a class="btn next"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="row mt-20">
                <div id="owl-related-works" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">

                    <?php $counter = 1; foreach ($imagesArr as $image) { ?>
                    <div class="work-item">
                        <div class="work-container">
                            <div class="work-img">
                                <a href="#img<?php echo $counter++; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $images_core->prepLocation . $image ?>" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <? } ?>
```

Main Image:

```
                    <div id="gallery_image">

                    <?php $counter = 1; foreach ($imagesArr as $image) { ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $images_core->prepLocation . $image ?>" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>" <?php echo $counter > 1 ? 'style="display:none;" ' : 'style="display:block;" id="active" '; ?> class="img<?php echo $counter++;?>">
                    <?php } ?>          
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please create a codepen or jsbin with an example? I would be happy to help you :)

generally, it would be best if you used jquery callbacks to replace the image src on the big image. But it will be a lot easier to explain if we had a proper jsbin.

In theory, the script needs to be far simpler, you can attach the onclick listener to all the small images. It will steal the `href` or `data-attribute` value from the clicked div. It will fadeout the current image, as a callback it will replace the `src` and fadein the element. And that is all there is to it.

Comment: current as it stands according to the  example above http://codepen.io/afagard/pen/KMpQQN

Comment: Generally, there is no need to complicate it. You started very good, and at one point in the middle decided to overcomplicate the script :D

Comment: So, on every click, i am doing the same thing as you did, i am taking the ID, converting it to a class, and querying the DOM for a valid element (big image). But at this point, i can just use the siblings() method to hide all others and show the clicked one :)

Comment: well that makes life super easy, didnt even know about the siblings method! awesome man! the simplicity of it. thanks ;)

Comment: Hehe, i always like things as simple as possible :D

Now, i used slideUp and slideDown. You can instead use .fadeIn and .fadeOut, or maybe add or remove class if you want a custom CSS animation, or you can use the .animate method... But this is by fat the easiest solution haha.

Comment: yea I'm just going to do a show hide, not a fan of too much animation, might do a fade, but I'll see how it pans out. again thanks!